# how to make the images be surrounded by a layer of space within the cell

Tags: tables, graphics

```
\begin{tabular}[h]{|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Proving Rectangle}\\
\hline
4 right angles & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{ProveRectangleA}}\\
\hline
Parallelogram with 1 right angle & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{ProveRectangleB}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular} \end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: unrelated but `tabular` does not have an `[h]` option.

Answer (score 2):

With the use of the `cellspace` package, you can achive a border of white space around the image.  `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` can be set to a length f your choice using the `setlength` command.  In the example, I have also added a less wordy and slightly different variant of achieving top aligned images using the `adjustbox` package and the `valign=t` option. (Compare the alignment of the image the frst and second image with respect to the lines of text in the corresponding rows in the left column.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|Sc|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Proving Rectangle}\\
  \hline
  4 right angles & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{ProveRectangleA}}\\
  \hline
  Parallelogram with 1 right angle & \includegraphics[scale=0.3,valign=t]{ProveRectangleB}  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty line with  `\\ &`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}


\begin{document}
   \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Proving Rectangle}\\
\hline
4 right angles & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-a}}\\
&\\ % <----------- added
\hline
Parallelogram with 1 right angle & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image-b}}\\
&\\ % <------------- added
\hline
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good the question and all the answers. My compliments.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you very much. I really appreciate your compliments.